# cannot get Foundation menu to work with reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I cant figure out why the following code wont create the foundation menu for me. Below is the super simplified version of my code:

```
        var MenuDisplay = React.createClass({

            render: function(){
                console.log("menu display render");
                var menu = (true)?
                <ul className="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
                            <li>
                                <a id="profile_name">Welcome
                                </a><ul className="menu">
                                    <li>profile</li>
                                    <li className="logout">logout</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        : null;
                return(
        <div>
                    {menu}
                    <FoundationPlugin />
                    </div>
                )
            }
        });

        var FoundationPlugin = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                //applying foundation() the whole document 
                $(document).foundation();
                return(
                    <div></div>
                );
            }
        });

        React.render(
            <MenuDisplay />,
            document.getElementById('myDiv')
        );
```

- There is nothing wrong with the jsx or html set up, I tested it in 'normal' html and running $().foundation on the menu. It properly display the menu
- the code above works if I apply the .Foundation() after all the code, instead of inside FoundationPlugin component. 
  However I have to do it this way. The reason being that I'm getting data from RestApi first, and that's going to take some time. If I put $().foundation() outside, by the time it hit the $().Foundation(), my component will still havent gotten the data and havent render the proper html tag. I have to run $().foundation only after all the rendering are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React components have several lifecycle functions. If you need to wait for rendering to be done, and the actual DOM to be updated, then `componentDidMount` is what you need.

```
var MenuDisplay = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function(){
    // Do stuff that relies on your DOM being rendered here.
    // Usually anything related to external libs like jQuery etc.
  },
  render: function(){
    ....
    ....
  }
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing me to the right direction! while componentDidMount didnt work in my case, componentDidUpdate worked perfectly.